# Regex: Match 'no characters' between strings

Tags: regex

I have to verify that strings match the following format before the first whitespace (if there is one):

- Up to 3 leading letters
- At least 4 consecutive digits
- Up to 3 trailing letters

To give examples, the following are valid:

- `1234`
- `Abc123456DeF`
- `1234 blah+`
- `XyZ01234`

I'm having trouble avoiding this case however: `123a+b blah`

So far I have `(^\w{0,3}\d{4}\w{0,3})\s*` but the problem lies in making sure a non-letter isn't caught in the first section.

I can see a couple solutions:

- Run regex twice, first getting the string up to the first whitespace `([^\s]+)` then apply regex again to that making sure it ends in up to 3 letters `(^\w{0,3}\d{4}\w{0,3}$)`. This is what I do now, but surely there's a way to do this in one expression - I just can't figure out how
- Make sure no non-letters exist between the (potential) 3 trailing letters and the (potential) whitespace. `(^\w{0,3}\d{4}\w{0,3}no non-letters)\s*`
  I've tried negative lookahead `(?!.*)` but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: `+` is special symbol. Should it be counted when you say `letters` ? Also `up to` is not clear. It should be `at least` or `at most`. `\w` character class don't have `+` in it.

Comment: How does `1234 blah+` fits into specifications ?

Comment: @Rahul When I say letters I mean the characters a-z/A-Z, so not +. `Up to` and `at most` are basically the same thing I don't understand the confusion there. `\w` doesn't have the `+` indeed, I chose it because it covers the same bases as a-z/A-Z. Non-letter characters can be included after the first whitespace, hence why I mentioned the format needs to be followed before the first whitespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regex:** `(^[A-Za-z]{0,3}\d{4,}[A-Za-z]{0,3})(?:$|\s+)`

`\w` is same as `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, so to match just letters you should use `[A-Za-z]`.

`(?:$|\s+)` matches end of string or at least one whitespace (hence ignoring the rest of the string).

Comment: `\w` is not always the same as `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, it is equal to `[\p{L}\p{N}_]` by default in Python 3 and .NET.

Comment: I'm now seeing that `\w` doesn't necessarily mean just `[0-9a-zA-Z]` so I think `[a-zA-Z]` is just what I need. This seems to solve the problem perfectly, it was wrapping my head around the `(?:$|\s+)` part that confused me. Thanks!

Comment: @JCK: I don't understand how is it solution when it's clearly failing on 
 [1234 blah+](https://regex101.com/r/5iAXW3/1/)

Comment: You do not need a plus after `\s`. It is actually almost the same regex as mine.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>This regex satisfy your specifications.</strike>

**Regex:** `^\w{0,3}\d{4,}\w{0,3}\s?$`

**Explanation:**
According to your specifications.

`\w{0,3}?` Up to 3 leading letters

`\d{4,}` At least 4 consecutive digits

`\w{0,3}?` Up to 3 trailing letters

> I have to verify that strings match the following format before the first whitespace (if there is one):

`\s?` hence an optional space[.](https://regex101.com/r/KP8Rp1/5/)

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KP8Rp1/4/)**

**Note:-** I am keeping this as stroked out because there were many shortcomings pointed out in comments. So to maintain the context of comments.

---

**Solution:**

Like I said in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971086/regex-match-no-characters-between-strings/43971173#comment74974209_43971173).

> @JCK: Problem is . . even whitespace is optional. Thus making it difficult to differentiate between first and second part.

Now employing a lookahead solves this problem. Complete regex goes like this.

**Regex:** `^(?=.*[0-9]{4,}[A-Za-z]{0,3}(?:\s|$))[A-Za-z]{0,3}[0-9]{4,}[A-Za-z]{0,3}\s*?(?:\S*\s*)*$`

**Explanation:**

1. `(?=.*[0-9]{4,}[A-Za-z]{0,3}(?:\s|$))` This positive lookahead makes sure that the first part defined by your specifications is matched. It looks for mentioned specs and either a `\s` or `$` i.e end of string. Thus matching the first part.
2. `[A-Za-z]{0,3}[0-9]{4,}[A-Za-z]{0,3}\s*?(?:\S*\s*)*` Rest of the regex is as per the specifications.

<kbd>**[Check by entering strings one by one.](https://regex101.com/r/LxesU0/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: @JCK: You mentioned three specifications to be applied before a whitespace is found. In `1234 blah+` how are those specifications met ?

Comment: @JCK: Okay so you mean after first space is encountered there could be any number of characters ?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean: after the first whitespace anything goes, before that is where the specifications matter

Comment: @JCK: One last point. Can there be more whitespaces after first whitespace ? Something like `aaa1234sss dddd fff gggg` ?

Comment: it is capturing the following cases, which it shouldn't: `1234+`, `1234abcdefg`. EDIT yes there can be more than 1 whitespace

Comment: @JCK: Problem is . . even whitespace is optional. Thus making it difficult to differentiate between first and second part.

Comment: @JCK: I think [this is the regex](https://regex101.com/r/P6B6gh/1/) you are looking for.

Comment: it's still capturing the cases I mentioned before: `1234+` and `1234abcd`. Regex has been nothing but trouble for me but I'm trying to learn to do things the 'proper' way, unfortunately this particular problem has become a major annoyance. Do you know of a way to solve the first solution? ie. take the regex of `everything up to first whitespace` then apply  `(^\w{0,3}\d{4}\w{0,3}$)` to that, all within one statement? Thanks for the assistance by the way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144278/discussion-between-rahul-and-jck).